# How to use Courier Tracking API in Fedex

Tags: php, api, fedex

I am trying to user Fedex API in my website. For tracking Courier records.
I have downloaded the files from Fedex [document](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html).

I have successfully able to use shipping functionality using  `CURL`.

But now I am having this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fedextest/fedex-tracking-api-wrapper-master/tests/TrackTest.php on line 5
```